# Play Framework 2. Multiple file uploading and processing

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to load multiple files at the same time with Play 2 and build some thumbnails for them with asynchronous api.
Uploading is work quite ok and great troubles come when image processing starts. 
The problem is as follows(a bit of desciption): files, which were fetched from request and collected into list are disappearing while image processing(take a lot of time).

And some samples here:

```
//part of controller
public static Result addPictures2(Long galleryId) {


        MultipartFormData body              = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        final List<FilePart> fileList       = body.getFiles(); 
        final Long fGalleryId               = galleryId;

        Promise<Boolean> promiseOfBool = Akka.future( 
                new Callable<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean call() {

                        Gallery gallery = Gallery.find.byId(fGalleryId);

                        for(FilePart part : fileList) {
                            File    picFile     = part.getFile();
                            Logger.debug("picFile: " + picFile.exists());
                            String  extension   = FilenameUtils.getExtension(part.getFilename());
                            GalleryItem item    = new GalleryItem("", "", picFile, extension);
                            gallery.addItem(item);
                        }

                        gallery.update();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );



        return async(
            promiseOfBool.map(
                new Function<Boolean, Result>() {
                    public Result apply(Boolean b) {
                        return redirect(
                                controllers.backend.routes.GalleryContentController.showGalleryItemsPage(fGalleryId)
                            );
                    }
                }
            )
        );


    }
```

So

> gallery.addItem(item);

takes a lot of time, and next call for

> Logger.debug("picFile: " + picFile.exists());

says that picFile do not exists. I know, this is because those files are temporary... but should they exists emm a little bit longer? And the question is: how to solve this trouble. Should I look at temporary files in java?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like solution is very simple. I should keep files in my own cache till I use them in Akka worker. After processing with Akka I could delete it myself.
The reason of such behaviour is not to waste file descriptors. Files fetched from request will be deleted before Akka starts.
Anyway this is just a guess. I'll try it now.

P.S. Yes. There is a problem. Solution is to keep those files as temporary and delete only after processing.

Comment: File upload questions are often asked, could you please update the question and add proper code of the solution that is working for you?